# API Gateway to Lambda function Form Data issue

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am setting up a Lambda function that will be triggered by an API Gateway V2 endpoint.

There will be Form Data sent through however when it reaches the lambda function it is in a strange way.

The Event Body is base64 encoded. So I have to decode it.

`event = base64.b64decode(event['body'])`

> b'----------------------------809582309949071767113581\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="command"\r\n\r\n\r\n----------------------------809582309949071767113581\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="text"\r\n\r\this is the text \r\n----------------------------809582309949071767113581\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="token"\r\n\r\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n----------------------------809582309949071767113581\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="user_name"\r\n\r\nkim_d\r\n----------------------------809582309949071767113581\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"\r\n\r\n14239\r\n----------------------------809582309949071767113581\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="response_url"\r\n\r\nhttp:"//example.com\r\n----------------------------809582309949071767113581--\r\n'

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No you are not missing anything. That's how the data gets to lambda from API Gateway, after receiving the arguments upon getting triggered you have to decode and use it.

I was facing the same challenge when I tried to read data from a file and send it to lambda through API gateway. I was unable to any other way apart from sending the data as byte string.

Not Sure what is the necessity to design it this way.